# Mathematica ColorFunctionScaling

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica, plot

I have a `ListDensityPlot` of a temperature in a can in Mathematica. I am animating its development over time, but the `ColorFunction` always sets the highest temperature of the current step to correspond to Red. I want my max temperature overall to correspond to red, how do I do that (I assume it's got something to do with `ColorFunctionScaling`)?

Here's my code

```
Animate[ListDensityPlot[Dev[[m, All, All]], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"])], {m, 1, t, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and manually scale the color function, using something like

```
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {min, max}, {0,1}]&)
```

where `min` and `max` are the overall minimum and maximum (probably `Through[{Min,Max}[Dev]]`.)

Comment: Thank you Brett, you truly are a Champion <3